# Can Some not all mountains actually be Giant petrified Tree Stumps?

Tags: soil-science

Is it possible That The process that had occurred with the flood have actually petrified ginormous tree stumps during the flood??

Comment: Which flood are you talking about? Furthermore, have you considered how high a tree must have been if it's stump is about 3 km high?

Comment: A huge number of mountains are volcanic.

Comment: Noahs flood. The world flood, which is copied and translated into many other accounts bcuz it was their own way to explain what had occured. Such as Gilgamesh, Ragnarok, i am sure many others. But many others also speak of A Giant tree, A world tree. This thing was Huge and in Lebanon none the less. Now then. During pre flood, Heathens cut this tree down. Now when the flood occured, the stump as well as others giant trees i am sure, were covered by sediments and the heat from the under water volcanoes made it hot. So.. Is it possible that the Mountain range in Lebanon is actually a tree stump?

Answer (score 5):

> ...the process that had occurred with the flood...

I'm assuming that you are talking about the biblical flood. There is no evidence that the flood had ever occurred.

---

> Can...mountains actually be Giant petrified Tree Stumps?

No. Petrified trees are made of silica with a very distinct texture as [observed in the microscope](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Polished_petrified_wood_cells.jpg#/media/File:Polished_petrified_wood_cells.jpg). All mountains are made of other things. For example, granite, limestone, basalt, and various types of rock. Some mountains are made of sandstone quartzite, which are compositionally similar to what petrified wood is made off. However, sandstone is just hardened sand, and quartzite is sandstone that has become even more hardened due to the high temperatures and pressures deep in the Earth. They looking nothing like petrified wood.

Comment: To be fair there actually are two candidates for the origin of the biblical flood story, neither of them were global but they _were_ big enough to kill all life any surviving witness ever knew.

Comment: Not to mention we can actually track the formation is mountains, You can actually see that they are either  uplifted horizontal layers or volcanic.

Comment: I heard as correct at France, from geologist that had studied the zone at Turkey, [this hypothesys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Sea_deluge_hypothesis). After an earthquake on Bosforo strait, Black Sea basin suddenly become flooded, being the geological event "narrated" in many religious histories.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are talking about. There are geological formations called volcanic plugs, which bear a strong resemblance to gigantic tree stumps and might easily fool people who knew nothing about geology into thinking that's what they were. Many millions of years ago the magma inside a volcanic cone cooled and solidified, and the volcano became extinct. During the course of millions of years of weathering, the softer, outer parts of the volcano were eroded away, leaving just the harder core still standing. Edinburgh Castle is sited on top of one of these volcanic plugs, but the presence of the castle disguises its tree-stump-like appearance. This particular volcanic plug is about 350 million years old.  I don't think there are any which are three kilometres high, this one certainly isn't. Devil's Tower in Wyoming USA is a good example of the kind of plug I mean, but I have seen better ones (see Wickepedia). Anyone with a knowledge of botany would know that a tree of such dimensions would be a physical impossibility.

Comment: PS  Ancient volcanic plugs are the only geological formations which look like gigantic tree stumps.

Comment: If anyone has witnessed this plug event plz let me know. Volcanoes are messy. When the flood Had indeed occured, all sediments were mixed and as they fell into place they began forming mountains. Heres a fun fact, The weight of the sediment decides when it falls into place. They stacked upon eachother forming mountains. NowThere's accounts of a World tree spoken of by different peoples such as vikings for one. Ezekiel 31 gives account of this Assyrian Cedar tree which is now lebanon. Now its a stump. There were many floods, but There was One World flood. Could Yggdrasil been this tree?

Comment: I thought I made it plain that the only geological formations resembling gigantic tree stumps were ancient volcanic plugs. Lots of people have witnessed them, as there are dozens around the world. I have seen a photograph of one which looked exactly like a tree stump except it was thousands of times as large, but I forget where it was. . They have nothing to do with floods or sediments, or trees, but there is a connection with mountains because volcanoes are usually found among mountains. Don't look for geological information in the Bible, because you won't find any.

Comment: I see what ur saying but not all are plugs. I do have to ask, how would a plug come out from the ground if its a plug? Notice the difference beteen a plug and a plant. Ones still messy.